# My query is not returning empty or null values from the table

Tags: mysql

This is my query and it is not returning empty or null column values in a particular row

```
SELECT if(b2b_image1 is not null or b2b_image1='' ,"1", "0") + if(b2b_image2 is not null or b2b_image2='', "1", "0") + if(b2b_image3 is not null or b2b_image3='', "1", "0") + if(b2b_image4 is not null or b2b_image4='', "1", "0") as non_empty FROM b2b_checkin_report WHERE b2b_booking_id='105';
```

Here, the 4th column b2b_image4 is empty, but it is returning me 4 as output
like...

```
non_empty
   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't fully understand what you are trying to do. You want an indication of each column if its a null or an empty string? If so , you have a few errors :

```
SELECT if(b2b_image1 is null or b2b_image1='' ,'1', '0')
      ,if(b2b_image2 is null or b2b_image2='', '1', '0') 
      ,if(b2b_image3 is null or b2b_image3='', '1', '0') 
      ,if(b2b_image4 is null or b2b_image4='', '1', '0') 
FROM b2b_checkin_report
WHERE b2b_booking_id='105';
```

Or, you want to see the count of the columns that are null or empty, in that case your problem was that you used `IS NOT NULL` instead of `IS NULL` , which does exactly the opposite of what you intended :

```
SELECT if(b2b_image1 is null or b2b_image1='' ,1, 0)
        + if(b2b_image2 is null or b2b_image2='', 1, 0) 
        + if(b2b_image3 is null or b2b_image3='', 1, 0) 
        + if(b2b_image4 is null or b2b_image4='', 1, 0) as empty_cnt
FROM b2b_checkin_report
WHERE b2b_booking_id='105';
```

Also, for string use a single quote sign `'` and not double `"` , although you don't even need strings here, you are summing up numbers, so use numbers!.